# Capture Image Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I'm trying to capture an image using the device's camera in my Android app and display it in an ImageView using CameraX for camera interactions and Coil as the image loading library. However, I'm facing issues with using the deprecated onActivityResult method, and I want to implement a modern approach using ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture().  Here's my current code:

```
private fun camera() {
    val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        val bitmap = data?.extras?.get("data") as Bitmap
        binding.imageView.load(bitmap) {
            crossfade(true)
            crossfade(1000)
            transformations(CircleCropTransformation())
        }
    }
}
```

I understand that onActivityResult is deprecated, and I want to update my code to use the modern ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture() API for capturing the image. Could someone please guide me on how to rewrite the camera() function and handle the image capture result using ActivityResultContracts.TakePicture()? Additionally, I would like to know how to display the captured image in the ImageView using Coil.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example:

#1 Create a custom lifecycle event observer you will use in the fragment/activity

```kotlin
class CameraXResultObserver(
    private val activity: FragmentActivity
) : LifecycleEventObserver {

    private lateinit var getData: ActivityResultLauncher<Bundle>
    private var doOnResult: (Bundle?) -> Unit = {}

    fun launch(extras: Bundle, doOnResult: (Bundle?) -> Unit) {
        this.doOnResult = doOnResult
        getData.launch(extras)
    }

    override fun onStateChanged(source: LifecycleOwner, event: Lifecycle.Event) {
        if (event == Lifecycle.Event.ON_CREATE)
            getData = activity
                .activityResultRegistry
                .register(this.javaClass.name, CameraXContract()) {
                    doOnResult(it)
                }
    }
}
```

#2 Create a contract for activity result:

```kotlin
private class CameraXContract : ActivityResultContract<Bundle, Bundle?>() {
    override fun createIntent(context: Context, input: Bundle): Intent =
         Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
            .apply {
                putExtras(input)
            }


    override fun parseResult(resultCode: Int, intent: Intent?): Bundle? {
        if (resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK)
            return null

        return intent?.extras ?: Bundle()
    }

}
```

You can change input and output params to your needs. I used Bundle for input and output.

#3 Then add this CameraXResultObserver to fragment/activity lifecycle:

```kotlin
private val cameraXResultObserver: CameraXResultObserver
    by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
         CameraXResultObserver(requireActivity())
               .also(lifecycle::addObserver)
}
```

#4 And finally launch the Camera activity and handle the result:

```kotlin
private fun camera() {
  cameraXResultObserver.launch(
                    extras = bundle,
                    doOnResult = { bundle -> 
                        //handle the result here
                    }
                )
}
```